# How to modify \w in PS1 conditionally?

Tags: bash, prompt

Everything I work on lives inside the icloud directory, making my `bash` prompt very long:

```
~/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Projects/foo/bar/baz @master $
```

My prompt is:

```
PS1='\w\[\e[1;35m\]$(__git_ps1 " @%s") \[\e[1;32m\]\$\[\e[m\] '
```

Is it possible to replace only the occurence of`/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/` in `\w` into something like `icloud` thus producing a better prompt like the following?

```
~/icloud/Projects/foo/bar/baz @master $
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it using parts of @ilkkachu's answer by using a function `cwd` that updates the path dynamically:

```bash
cwd() {
    cwd=${PWD/\/Users\/htor/\~}
    echo ${cwd/\Library\/Mobile Documents\/com~apple~CloudDocs/icloud}
}
PS1='$(cwd)\[\e[1;35m\]$(__git_ps1 " @%s") \[\e[1;32m\]\$\[\e[m\] '
```

It's not pretty, but at least my prompt is pretty again!

Answer (score 2):

Zsh has the "named directories" feature that pretty much automatically abbreviates the directory name in the prompt, too. I don't think Bash has the equivalent, but you could work around it by having `PROMPT_COMMAND` run a custom function to set a variable you then print in the prompt insetad of using `\w`.

E.g. this should replace an initial `/tmp/test` in the path with `~testdir`.

```
set_promptpath() {
    promptpath=$PWD;
    # do whatever replacement you like here
    promptpath=${promptpath/#\/tmp\/test/\~testdir}
}
PROMPT_COMMAND=set_promptpath
PS1='$promptpath\$ '
```